# MessageBox not showing (focused) after SaveFileDialog

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

For some reason after my SaveFileDialog, my app will never show the MessageBox. Is there something I'm missing? Or is this a threading issue?

I run the application as a Windows Form application using VS 2010 Express.

I do not get any exceptions.

To add: When I step through the code, all seems to go well. Which is weird, so I believe it is a timing issue.

Pointed out by LarsTech and others, the MessageBoxes do show up, however the focus is gone; in other words the MessageBox is pushed behind other windows or minimized. This is a problem.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
namespace SpeedDating
{
    class Program
    {
         [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

        string filename = "test.test"; // args[0];
        string ext = filename.Substring(filename.LastIndexOf('.'));
        SaveFileDialog dialog = new SaveFileDialog();
        dialog.Title = "SpeedDating App";
        dialog.RestoreDirectory = true;
        dialog.CheckFileExists = false;
        dialog.CheckPathExists = false;
        dialog.FileName = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + ext;

        DialogResult result = dialog.ShowDialog();
        if (result == DialogResult.OK && dialog.FileName != "")
        {
            try
            {
                FileStream outfs = File.Create(dialog.FileName);
                FileStream infs = File.Open(filename, FileMode.Open);
                infs.CopyTo(outfs);
                infs.Close();
                outfs.Close();
            }
            catch (NotSupportedException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Probably removed the original file.");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No path found to write to.");
        }

        MessageBox.Show("I came here and all I got was this louzy printline");

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're sure it doesn't throw another exception, ever?

Comment: Yeah I ran this code and it worked, is there anything else that comes up?

Comment: Confirm @Bearcat9425 finding.  The MessageBoxes show up behind the Visual Studio editor though.

Comment: I run dual screens, so my editor was on one screen and the app ran on the other so they worked fine for me but yes I could see on a single screen that happening. Is @LarsTech finding what your problem is?

Comment: Try adding `catch (Exception ex)` if there isn't other exception, this should cover it.. Also If I were you I would add the if conditions in brakes -> `if ((result == DialogResult.OK) && (dialog.FileName != ""))` just to be sure...

Comment: Have you tried to put it first separately in a non-threaded situation just to confirm if it is a threading issue?

Comment: @Edper: How would I do that? It is currently a single threaded application (STAThread), so I think that comes down to the same.

Comment: @LarsTech: Could very well be, might not be a real big issue then.

Comment: The MessageBoxes do show up indeed but are hidden, also in published version.

Comment: That's why MessageBox.Show() has overloads that accept a *window* argument.  Which ensures that the box is always on top of that window.  Leaving it up to MessageBox to find a window can be iffy in certain cases.  Like this one where you don't *have* a window.  It is certainly best to avoid bolting a user interface onto a program that doesn't have one.

Comment: Just to confirm with others I tried and it works. Although you could not see it (at least the two MessageBox) not until you click on the Task Bar. I saw the messages "No path found to write to." and "I came here and all I got was this louzy printline" when I cancelled the Dialog box.

Comment: What Hans posted is *the* answer, even though he missed the answer box by a few inches. Still wondering though how you're going to implement speed dating a file.

Comment: @Cody Gray: Yeah, I know. I upvoted it him if that reassures you. Speed dating a file takes an inputstream and an outputstream and one writes to another. Oh, I'm so vulgar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried this one and it showed right away:

```
 MessageBox.Show(new Form() { WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized, TopMost = true }, "You clicked Cancel button", "Cancel");
```

Comment: This is close to what I eventually did; creating a form with above settings, however one form to rule them all.

Answer (score 2):

Try this for your Message Box.

```
MessageBox.Show(this,"Probably removed the original file.");
```

Comment: It works if I create a form which is shown with Show(). Else it won't display the MessageBox. However if I create a new form and show it, I will have an empty window of the form, which I don't want.

Comment: I just made an edit basically you want to tell the messagebox that its owner is the current form your in so it will bring itself to the front, try it with this. Instead of the new form.  I was posting my console mess.  I forgot you said you were running as a winforms application.

Comment: The "this" would be invalid because it is inside the static Main().

Comment: He said its running as a windows forms application not a console. If its a winforms application this would be correct.  For a console application no he would need to create the new form as another answer posted, or how my answer was posted before when I was thinking console.

Answer (score 1):

I created a new project and pasted your code and it works for me. Make sure you have done a full rebuild before running. Also, with this line:

```
dialog.FileName = DateTime.Now.ToString(format) + "." + ext;
```

The dialog box will have a file name to begin with. Therefore, only hitting the cancel button (assuming you don't clear the save dialog first) will trigger the message box. Either way, I got the message box to pop up by failing your IF test either way. Your code looks alright.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should put the `SaveFileDialog` in a using to ensure its disposal prior to the MessageBox call:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
namespace SpeedDating
{
    class Program
    {
         [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string filename = "test.test"; // args[0];
            string ext = filename.Substring(filename.LastIndexOf('.'));
            using (SaveFileDialog dialog = new SaveFileDialog())
            {
                dialog.Title = "SpeedDating App by K.Toet";
                dialog.RestoreDirectory = true;
                dialog.CheckFileExists = false;
                dialog.CheckPathExists = false;
                dialog.FileName = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + ext;

                DialogResult result = dialog.ShowDialog();
                if (result == DialogResult.OK && dialog.FileName != "")
                {
                    try
                    {
                        FileStream outfs = File.Create(dialog.FileName);
                        FileStream infs = File.Open(filename, FileMode.Open);
                        infs.CopyTo(outfs);
                        infs.Close();
                        outfs.Close();
                    }
                    catch (NotSupportedException ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Probably removed the original file.");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("No path found to write to.");
                }
            }

            MessageBox.Show("I came here and all I got was this louzy printline");
        }
    }
}
```